# Add typescript paths to Storybook - Webpack v5?

Tags: typescript, webpack, plugins, storybook

Storybook comes with a built in Webpack configuration and till Webpack v4 it was possible to use [tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin) and declare custom tscofnig (or any other plugin) as:

```js
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  ...,
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
       config.resolve.plugins = [new TsconfigPathsPlugin()];
       return config;
  }
```

Has anyone made it work with Webpack v5 or used any other package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would still prefer solution with plugin configuration in `main.ts` file which would be more proper imo.
But as workaround adding environment variable works:
`"storybook": "TS_NODE_PROJECT=tsconfig.dev.json start-storybook"`